# Can we pass a jsp variable to jQuery ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I a have a jQuery ready function given below, I need to pass a value to the `myLocFn()`. What I am asking is, as we are using ready function ,if it possible to pass a jsp value to myLocFn().

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myDiv").myLocFn();     // need to pass a value here                  
});
</script>
```

I have included the js path as well `<script src="myLocFn.js"></script>`. 
Where the my js starts with,

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myLocFn= function(options) {
..... // need to get the value here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a JSP variable inside script section using server code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jspVar="JSP_value"; // use expression tag in JSP here
</script>
```

Then refer in your jQuery code, just like a JavaScript variable, as u assigned ur JSP value to JS variable in above line

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myLocFn= function(options) {
    alert(jspVar); //here u can see 
}
```

**Edit:** Please make sure that jspVar should be defined before accessing. You can check this from the rendered HTML

Comment: Error: 'jspVar' is undefined.  (function($){... in myLocFn.js which is included in the jsp, from where I need to pass the value.

Comment: Before including myLocFn.js, I have defined `jspVar` globally. And worked. Thanks.

Comment: If JSP_value is not a string, you may wish to avoid the quotes. This will not work as expected for a boolean, for example.